Movie with a light bulb fight game
I remember seeing a while ago, possibly on tv, a scene from what I think was a bit of a sappy coming of age movie. The scene was a couple of young boys running around their street, stealing the light bulbs from people's porch lights, and then throwing them at eachother as a big happy game.
There was also this beautiful song playing in the background which is the main reason I want this identified.
Also, I may be wrong, but I think the light bulb game started just after the two kids has had some kind of heart-warming talk.
I think it was late 2000's. Pretty sure it was American. The kids were mid to late teens. As for other scenes I can't remember anything else.

Approximate year? Country\language? Do you remember other scenes or anything else?

I think it was late 2000's. Pretty sure it was American. The kids were mid to late teens. As for other scenes I can't remember anything else.

I think you're looking for the coming of age drama Accidents Happen from 2009 with Geena Davis.

There are dysfunctional families... and then there are the Conways. After a family tragedy, 15-year-old Billy Conway has become the de facto glue between his bitter mom, distant brother, and stoic dad. But when Billy starts to act out, everything changes for him and his family. 

Billy befriends his teen neighbor Doug and in one scene, they swipe lightbulbs from the neighborhood and throw them at each other. You can see the scene in the trailer around 0:38:




That's the one! Thanks so much, been bothering me for ages!
